# How do re-open the Github extension after I have closed it in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2017

I have closed the Github extension window in my Visual Studio 2017 and I do not know how to reopen it. I can not find it in any of the menu options?

How do re-open the Github extension after I have closed it in Visual Studio 2017? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can go to *View > Team Explorer*. This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

In Visual Studio 2017 menu navigate:

`View > Other Windows > GitHub`

This will reopen the GitHub pane.